# Service onDestroy() called when activity started from another one

Tags: android, android-intent

Firstly, sorry for my English if it's not enough good. I'm having some problems in my application. 
Starting, my app has multiple activities and one service which works in background since the first activity execute it. If I press back button on my root activity, I exit from the app but the service continue working. Then, I go into the app back, and the service work perfectly. My problem comes when I press a button to exit the application (there, I stop service and finish the root activity mainly) and then exit without any problem, when I want to enter the app again, the service is started, but if I want to change to another activity (which doesn't have the serviceConnection) my service get called onDestroy() method without any reason for that. I don't have how to continue, because the usual way to execute in this case is the service go on working as the first case.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: your question needs "What have you done" supports, as its quite vague.

Comment: In this moment I can't support my question with codes, but I will try to provide later. What do you need for this?

Comment: For now, I'd like to know how theory you'd manage on this situation. I want to provide you the service is started with START-STICKY code from my CustomApplication constructor with startService(intent) method.

Answer (score 0):

There is for sure a reason why onDestroy gets called.

In the first section of 'Services' in the developer guide, you can read the following:

> Multiple components can bind to the service at once, but when all of
>   them unbind, the service is destroyed. [(link)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

So, if all components unbind from the service, the service will get destroyed. When you enter the activity that is not bound to the service, the service will be destroyed.

I'm wondering why you don't want your service to be destroyed since you don't need it in your 'another' activity?

Comment: Hi LJoose, thanks for your reply. I need the service active because in background it must receive info from the server constantly from time to time. Your theory get nearer to the problem, but there is a question, why, in the first cycle before press exit button, can I enter to the activity unbounded without any problem and the service continue working, and after press exit button, and reentering the app, in the same activity the service calls onDestroy()?

Comment: The Service is destroyed when all components unbind. So probably, when onDestroy is called on your Service, onDestroy is called on your Activity that binds to the Service. If you put debug messages in the lifecycle methods (include the Activity name!), you can see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks you again, LJoose, as soon as I can, I'll debug lifecycles method, but i can say from right now last lifecycle method executed when I switch to another activity without service bounded is onStop() root activity's method, which has service bounded.